# How to execute a javascript inside a Struts2 iterator?

Tags: javascript, struts2, iterator

I'm developing a shopping web site application. In my application clients can watch the daily offers. I have a table named offer in database. I'm using Struts2 framework. I have an action class named, `OfferView.java`. In this class I'm adding all offers' end dates to a List.(`List<String[]>`). My purpose is, I need to run a countdown timer according to the end date of every offer. In my view, I tried to run a javascript inside Struts2 iterator. But I failed. For the countdown timer I'm using `jquery.countdown.js`. I tried with this-

```
<s:iterator value="days">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
           var day ='<s:property value="days[0]"/>';
           var austDay = new Date();
           austDay = new Date(day+1, - 1, 25);
           $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
           $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
        });
    </script>
 </s:iterator>
```

This iterator is working. When I'm adding `<s:property value="days[0]"/>` outside the script it's working well. How could I run a javascript inside an iterator? Is it possible, If it is how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and put the function outside of iterator, like so:

```
function countdown(day) {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(day + 1, -1, 25);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: austDay
    });
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
}
```

and then in your iterator try to call it: `countdown('<s:property value="days[0]"/>');`

Comment: This is not working. I tried to this. When I use this I got only plain text `countdown(2013);` like this.

Comment: I'm using `jquery.countdown.js`. And timer is calling as `<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>`

Comment: did you encapsulate it into <script></script>?

Comment: No problems, I'm glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Strtus2 things are running on the serverside while javascript is client based thing so you can't.Use seperate Javascript block outside and access the things based on the id or name soemthing.

Here if you have thousand items then Iterator will duplicate Javascript block thousand times.

```
 1,  User Struts2 Tags to generate images(for example) like this,
    <div id="item_here name or id based on the time"><img ></img></div>

 2, In Javascript or Jquery use counter every time interval to find valid Items.
There get all items starting with the id "item_".

 3,Now check its time with current time and if it is expired simply hide or 
whatever you wish.
```

Comment: Could please tell me how can I do this.